# Drupal search not working the way it should be

Tags: search

I have plenty of contents (nodes) on my drupal-page.

When I use **search/node** to find certain terms (words), I got results. That's good so far.

Now I created some new contents (after months). These newly created ones contain *new terms (words)* that haven't been used in the older contents.

When I now search for these *new terms (words)* at **search/node** there are no search results! And I don't understand it, because they're even listed in database-table *search_index*.

I suspected some orphaned node-ids (nid) to cause the problem, went to phpmyadmin and found such in the *search_index* table, deleted them, but still: the problem remains.

What can I do? Desperately searching for days to solve this.

Many thanks.
Selim

Comment: do you run the cron?

Comment: Yes!
What I else tried:
1. Rebuild Index (admin/config/search/settings), ran CRON - nothing happened.
2. Uninstalled Search-Module, cleared caches, ran CRON, installed it again, rebuild index, ran CRON - NO-THING!

Comment: One more thing: I use the module **search-auto-complete**. When I type in the search field such a _new term (word)_ then I got results and when I click one of those I come to the content that contains the _term_. This is something really funny.

Comment: Am one step further: I found that the search term isn't listed in the database table _search_total_. So I inserted it manually and it worked.
**BUT: this is not the solution of course.** It seems there is something wrong with the indexation of search terms. What can I do?

Comment: It seems there is a problem with the search_update_totals()-function in  /modules/search/search.module or the search_cron()-function is not invoked.

Comment: this is bizarre

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with the database. Probably a function in the *search.module* is prevented from updating / inserting in _search_total_-table. I have no idea. Do you?